# quick xslt for-each question

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I have an XML document that has this:

```
<keywords>
<keyword>test</keyword>
<keyword>test2</keyword>
<keyword>test3</keyword>
<keyword>test4</keyword>
</keywords>
```

And i want to use XSLT to print it out in HTML like this:

```
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
<li>test4</li>
</ul>
```

What would my XSLT look like?  I tried this:

```
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="keywords/keyword">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="keyword"/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

but that doesn't print out the keyword value, just a blank item.

```
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="keywords">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="keyword"/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

doesn't work (for obvious reasons), but at least it prints the first keyword!

suggestions?  thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="keywords/keyword">    
  <li><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

using text() should get you the text inside the keyword node

Comment: Actually, in this case, using `select="."` will work too (the node will be atomized, which effectively means a concatenation of values of all nested text nodes on all levels).

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest avoiding `for-each` here, and doing it using a template - it's more idiomatic in XSLT, especially when you have a clear one-to-one mapping:

```
<xsl:template match="keyword">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="keywords">
    <ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Agreed - major programmer issue in adapting to XSLT is to think in terms of for-each (and call-template) instead of using apply-tempaltes and match=

Comment: agreed. Avoid `for-each` where you can.

Comment: Agreed, but use xsl:apply-templates without its select attribute only when the XML schema is well known and stable; otherwise, if there's any tag whose the template is missing, it will be processed by default templates and its text content will be put on the output.

Comment: @Erlock: I usually start with a default rule for all nodes that simply calls `<xsl:apply-template/>`. That way you get tree propagation for all nodes, but no output, by default.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree to the `apply-templates` vs `for-each` argument. +1